# How to use the object MainWindow *mainwindow=new MainWindow(); in functions

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm developing a program that contains a MainWindow and a Widget called diagrama from QWidget, wich is the centralwidget of my mainwindow.

Now I created a object that i'm not enable to use.

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{   
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Diagrama* diagrama=new Diagrama();
    setCentralWidget(diagrama);

    ....}

void MainWindow::on_actionCor_triggered()
{
    QColor newcolor=QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::black,this,"Cor do pincel");
    if(newcolor.isValid()){
        diagrama->setPenColor(newcolor);
        ##qt do not recognize the object diagrama, and i can't access the function of that class}
    }
```

How can i use it?i saw this in some examples, of creating an object of that class and using it later in the functions.

I tried to use:
diagrama=new Diagrama();

But it doesn't work either, i really don't know what to do.

Comment: 1) Add the following line to the .h in the private part of the class: `private: Diagrama* diagrama;`

Comment: 2) change `Diagrama* diagrama=new Diagrama();` to `diagrama=new Diagrama();`

Comment: there is de diagrama.h and the mainwindow.h, i'm supposed to add in the mainwindow right?

Comment: yes, you are right;

Comment: but to do this i have to include "diagrama.h" in the mainwindow.h, and i after i do this it starts to appear a lot of errors

Comment: no, you have to add `class Diagram;` before `class MainWindow: public xxxx {...`, read about forward declaration;

Comment: I GOT IT thanks dude, you're an angel sz